# Switch Method for building a javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, calculator

I am trying to build a calculator by using a switch method for my operations. For some reason that i can't seem to figure out my addition function works, but my subtraction function won't. It may be a simple fix, but i am sorta a newbie. Any insight would be great!! thanks.

```js
  

   var operatorPressed = false;
 var prevOperand = 0;
 var currentOperand = 0;
 var operationRequested = '';

// Creates calculator display input
 var displayNumbers = document.getElementById("display");  
  
// Clears calculator display and var a values
 function clearMemory()  {
   displayNumbers.value = "";
   prevOperand = 0;
   //var a = 0;
   //console.log(a);
 };

 function clearDisplay() {
   displayNumbers.value = "";
 };

// Displays values on calculator screen
 var displayValue = function(num)    {
   if (displayNumbers.value.length > 9)  {
     displayNumbers.value = "ERROR";
   } else    { 
     displayNumbers.value = num;
     //document.getElementById("display").value += Num;
   };
 };

 function handleNumberClick(num){
   currentOperand = operatorPressed ? num : displayNumbers.value + num;
   operatorPressed = false;
   displayValue(currentOperand);
 }

 function clearNumberEntered(){
   numberEntered='';
   clearDisplay();
 }
//Operators
//  function
 function handleOperationClick(operator){
   var result;
   operatorPressed = true;
   switch(operationRequested){
     case 'add':
       result = add(prevOperand, currentOperand);
       break;
     case 'subtract':
      result = subtract(prevOperand, currentOperand);
      break;
     default:
       result = '';
   }
   if(result){  //if an acutal computation occurs, we'll store overwrite the result to the prevOperand
     displayValue(result);
     prevOperand = result;
   } else {  //if no computation occurs we'll just set the input val as the prevOperand
     prevOperand = currentOperand;
   }
   console.log("operation:%s %d to %d", operationRequested, currentOperand, prevOperand );
   operationRequested = operator || operationRequested;
 }

 function add(num, adder){
   var sum = parseInt(num) + parseInt(adder);
   return sum;
 }

 function subtract(num, subtracter) {
  var difference = parseInt(num) - parseInt(subtracter);
  return difference;
 }
```

Comment: where is `operationRequested` coming from?  Where are `prevOperand` and `currentOperand` coming from? What happens when you add some debug to display what these variables are within and just before the switch  so you can see what the flow is doing?

Comment: Sorry. I edited and posted the full script.

Answer (score 0):

With what you have provided, the likely cause is `operationRequested` is being defined at the end of the function instead of before the `switch` statement where it is required.

The line at the end of the `function handleOperationClick(operator)`

```
operationRequested = operator || operationRequested;
```

should be above the line

```
switch(operationRequested){
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It seems I didn't post the full script. I declared my operationRequested variable up top.